# How to fix 'requests.exceptions.SSLError'

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I have read many articles about that but none worked for me. Also, I tried other solutions but still I'm stuck. I have a simple code:

```py
import requests

requests.get('https://s1.wcy.wat.edu.pl/ed1/', verify=False)
```

After setting verification to False I'm still getting an error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s1.wcy.wat.edu.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ed1/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: UNSUPPORTED_PROTOCOL] unsupported protocol (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

EDIT: Problem solved. For those who has the same problem. Make sure what is your website TLS verion. In my case it was 1.0. Then you must go to /etc/ssl and edit openssl.cnf. At the bottom you have

```
[system_default_sect]
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2
```

Just change 1.2 to 1.0. Worked for me

Comment: If you think your edit is the answer, please add it as an answer and accept it, that way others will find it easily. Thanks.

Comment: I want confirm 1.2->1.0 has solved my problem too. For some single target domain which makes troubles you can copy openssl.cnf -> some.domain.cnf and change 1.2->1.0 in the some.domain.cnf only.

Comment: To avoid using of system-wide settings you could setup custom SSL context in python, and set context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1, then fix context.options, and voila! (Some magic occurred).

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. By changing `verify=False` to `verify=ssl.CERT_NONE`, I fixed it.

Comment: doesn't solve it for me

Comment: For me is worked perfectly. 
`import ssl` on top

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I could not make it work with requests, or downgrade/upgrading Python, or using a new cert file in a system env... none of that worked

What worked is this:

```
import urllib3
from urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context

ctx = create_urllib3_context()
ctx.load_default_certs()
ctx.options |= 0x4  # ssl.OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT

with urllib3.PoolManager(ssl_context=ctx) as http:
    req = http.request("GET", "your_url")
    data_to_work_with = req .data
```

That goes through a combination of techniques. But, the main thing in there is this: `ctx.load_default_certs()`
It will load up your default certifications and should help you out.